# Why will my C# template not compile as a new project?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates

I created a template I wish to use for future projects. The template's project name is "Template". I went through Visual Studio file >> Export Template and exported the project as a project template.

I then created a new project, in a new solution using that template and called it something else. (XIVAchievements). It then replaced every occurence of "Template" with "XIVAchievements", as expected.

I can compile and run the Template project, but with the new project it will not compile. It gives an error every time I make any reference from the theme.xaml file. Theme.xaml starts off:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:XIVAchievements.Converters">
<!--Converters-->
<conv:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
<conv:BooleanToWindowBGSelectionConverter x:Key="BooleanToWindowBGSelectionConverter" />
```

The last 2 lines there provide errors, stating that:
"The name "BooleanToVisibilityConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:XIVAchievements.Converters"."

It does, of course. I have tried closing and reopening VS, as well as clean and rebuild, but nothing seems to work. When manually typing out the lines which error or the xmlns, intellisense correctly gives the options IO am referencing.

Comment: Is it in a different assembly? If so, you have to specify the assembly in the xmlns:xx="clr-namespace:blah.blah" attribute.

Comment: I don't think so? I literally have used the template and not changed anything at all, so the assembly should be the same?

Comment: So this is just only building the new project all by itself in isolation, not anything referencing it? This sounds vaguely familiar but I'm not putting my finger on it...

Comment: The class is public and all that sort of obvious stuff that I tend to forget?

Comment: Ahh, I have solved it now, sorry! I should never have called it Template, because throughout I had referencetes to templates, such as `<Setter Property="Control.Template">` etc. The .Template had chanced to .XIVAchievements also, which was what was causing the problems. Not to self: Call it something else next time!

Comment: Awesome! Glad you nailed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me. After looking at it long and hard, the problem was that I called it Template, and the word Template was used through my theme XAML, in places such as:

```
<Setter Property="Control.Template">
```

And the .Template was changing to .XIVAchievements. I put these back to .Template and it now works OK. Should give a different project name next time before exporting the template!